# Uploading a document template to multiple libraries at once

Tags: sharepoint, document

I have been tasked with uploading a new template to my companies Sharepoint sites. Each site has its own library and it is about 65 sites in total. I know how to upload a new template for one library at a time, but is there anyway to upload a template across all libraries?

I have search on google, stackoverflow and youtube, but everyone I have found only talks about one library at a time.

We are using Microsoft 365 with Sharepoint as a Service, so it should be the newest version of Sharepoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, there is no OOTB way to upload a document template to multiple libraries at once.
Maybe you can write a powershell to read and upload from csv files to multiple sharepoint libraries.